# EMMS with different playlists

Tags: emms

I'd like to open multiple playlists with `M-x emms-play-playlist` and have each one in a seperate *EMMS Playlist* buffer - at the same time.

Is it possible to have *different* "*EMMS Playlist*" buffers - at the same time?

My init.el has for EMMS just these lines of https://www.gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Quickstart-Guide:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/emms/lisp/")  
(require 'emms-setup)  
(emms-all)  
(emms-default-players)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `rename-buffer` and create a new playlist. EMMS functions keep a list of playlist buffers internally. You can see this list at any time by calling `(emms-playlist-buffer-list)`

The playlist/buffer that's being "currently" playing is pointed by `emms-playlist-buffer`

EDIT: I thought that "the current playlist-buffer" was updated automagically, but that doesn't seem to be your case. You can use **`(emms-playlist-set-playlist-buffer)`** to choose the buffer used as "current playlist"

Comment: I can use rename-buffer to rename the *EMMS Playlist* buffer to pl1. If I open then a new playlist, pl2 (for example), I just get it in the same buffer pl1! Calling (emms-playlist-buffer-list) in an elisp-file always gives a list of only one name. My init.el has just the four lines of gnu.org/software/emms/manual/#Quickstart-Guide. Should I change this configuration?

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate your playlist using `M-p` and `M-n`, look at the documentation of the buffer major mode with `C-h m`. You can make the active buffer the current playlist pressing `b`. You can add a track from the active buffer to the current playlist by pressing `a`. You can rename a playlist by simply renaming the buffer with `rename-buffer` (this way it becomes visible in the buffer list also). You can delete a playlist altogether with `K`. Doing `M-x emms` always switches to the current playlist.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Felipe Lema  I've found the following function. It works well for me. But I'm not sure about the code! So please be careful if you use it! Certainly an elisp programmer would find a better solution..

```
(defun my-emms-play-playlist (filename &optional wildcards)
  "makes a new EMMS playlist buffer from the playlist of filename" 
  (interactive
   (find-file-read-args "Find file: "
                        (confirm-nonexistent-file-or-buffer)))
  (emms-playlist-new (file-name-base filename))
  (switch-to-buffer (file-name-base filename))
  (emms-playlist-set-playlist-buffer)
  (emms-play-playlist filename)
)
```